# IonTab is not working properly when I click back to home, it is not refreshing to the respective tab

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic with React the IonTabs, but the Home tab, once I click in any other tab it is not getting back to home when I click.

```
<IonTabs>
        <IonRouterOutlet >
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/tab1" component={Tab1} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/tab2" component={Tab2} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/tab3" component={Tab3} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/home" />} exact={true} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
        <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
          <IonTabButton tab="home" href="/home">
            <IonIcon icon={home} />
            <IonLabel>Home</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="tab1" href="/tab1">
            <IonIcon icon={triangle} />
            <IonLabel>Tab 1</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="tab2" href="/tab2">
            <IonIcon icon={ellipse} />
            <IonLabel>Tab 2</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="tab3" href="/tab3">
            <IonIcon icon={square} />
            <IonLabel>Tab 3</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
        </IonTabBar>
      </IonTabs>
```

That is a way to solve it?

Comment: is it working for other tabs?

Comment: yes, it is. To Tab 1, Tab2 and Tab3 it is working fine, but to the Home that I included it is just appearing when the app loads, once I click in another tab it is not getting back to home.

Comment: The code you've shared should work fine. There must a problem somewhere else. When you attempt to go back to the home tab, do any errors appear in the dev tools console?

Comment: no, I tryied to find any error at the console, but it do not have any occurence.

Comment: In the mode desktop I could see the url is updated, but the page is not redirected.